# How can fill form "a" and automatically fill form "b" without showing it to the user?

Tags: forms, gravity

how can For example fill form “a” and automatically fill form “b” without showing it to the user in gravity form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like the following to your functions.php code to copy entry values from Form A to a new entry in Form B

```
//after submission
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_20', 'submit_form_b', 10, 2 );//replace 20 with the form id of Form A
function submit_form_b($entry_a, $form ){
    $entry_b = array(
        "form_id" => '30',//replace 30 with the form id of Form B
        "4" => $entry_a['1'],//replace "4" with the field id # from Form B. Replace '1' with the field id from Form A
        "5" => $entry_a['2'],//replace "5" with the field id # from Form B. Replace '2' with the field id from Form A
        "6" => $entry_a['3']//replace "6" with the field id # from Form B. Replace '3' with the field id from Form A
    );
    $create_entry = GFAPI::add_entry($entry_b);//this line creates a new entry for form B
}
```